# Upload and drag order of limited ammount of images

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload, plugins

i'm currently trying to do something for a website, where i can upload certain number of images (that quantity is dynamic and set by administrator of the site).

Watch them visually as a preview and be able to drag them around the container to set the the order of the items themselves.

something similar to this:

[image]

In that example i can click in of the squares and add as much images as they allow.
So far jQuery ui drag and drop works for the part asocciated to that. but i'm stuck on how to do the other part without the use of a plugin, not sure if anyone can give me an idea to do it with a jQuery solution or some existance plugin (who doesn't use flash)

Comment: I'm not clear what problem you're having?  The upload?  The drag and drop?  Saving the position of the photos?

Comment: i need to limit the quantity of images that can be selected and displayed in the container, lets say i want 10 images top, on file selection window allow to select 10, if not possible just process the first 10 selected images and ignore the rest.

Comment: You can store the images in an array, and if the array count reaches 10, disable the file upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html)
 I used it in some projects, works flawlessly for that matter.